# How to Fourier Transform multi images and save output into single object

Tags: python, loops, numpy, opencv, fft

I've got 96 different drone orthophotos in jpeg, of different dimensions and pixel sizes. I am trying to figure out the quality of each orthophoto by using a Non-reference based Image Quality technique. This entails transforming the image from the spatial domain to the frequency domain using Fourier Transforms. Analyzing the distribution of the frequencies provides insight into the amount of blur and noise within the image, and hence the quality of an image, as blur will decrease the amount of high frequencies.

However, to compare the quality of different images to one another, I need to create an index which has to be normalized over my entire data set, which will allow me to compare quality of images between images within my data set, but not to images outside of my data set (which is OK). To do this, I need to analyze the distribution of frequencies for all my 96 jpeg's together, and identify, say, the value of the top 15 % highest frequencies. If I know the highest frequencies of my data set, I can use this to define a threshold value to create my Image Quality index.

So my question is. How can I create a loop to read in all my images, apply a Gaussian Blur, apply a Fourier Transform, save the distributions of all frequencies into one object, and then identify the top 15 % of highest frequencies across my data set?

This is the code I have created so far to play around with one image:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Image1.jpg', 0)

# Smooting by gaussian blur to remove noise
imgSmooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)

# Fourier transform
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(imgSmooth), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
magnitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:, :, 0], dft_shift[:, :, 1]))
```

I am very new to python, as I normally code in R. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to calculate the mean frequency of each image, then get the frequency value of the top 15% of those images. We can do this in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

images_dir = 'folder/containing/images/'
images_list = os.listdir(images_dir)
images_mean_freq = []

for img_file in images_list:
    img_path = os.path.join(images_dir, img_file)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)

    # Smooting by gaussian blur to remove noise
    imgSmooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)

    # Fourier transform
    dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(imgSmooth), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
    magnitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:, :, 0], dft_shift[:, :, 1]))
    # get the standard deviation of the frequencies
    img_mean_freq = np.mean(magnitude_spectrum)
    images_mean_freq.append(img_mean_freq)
# then we can get the value of the top 15% highest frequencies, that is the 85% percentile of the distribution
top_15 = np.percentile(images_mean_freq, 85)
# finally we can select which images are above (or below) this top 15% threshold
images_above_top_15 = [images_list[idx] for idx in range(len(images_list)) if images_mean_freq[idx] > top_15]
```